# python: symbol lookup error: anaconda and cairo

Tags: python, ubuntu, cairo, graph-tool, nautilus

I have compiled graph-tool from source on Ubuntu 16.04 using `./configure CXXFLAGS="-std=gnu++14 -Wno-unused-local-typedefs" PYTHON="/home/pmj27/anaconda2/bin/python2.7" CAIROMM_LIBS="-L/home/pmj27/anaconda2/include/cairomm-1.0/cairomm" --enable-openmp`. I am now trying to run a script using graph-tool but at the following snippet it throws an error:

```
gt.graph_draw(g,pos = gt.arf_layout(g, max_iter=0),output_size=(3000,3000),vertex_surface = image, vertex_size = 150, vertex_halo=False, vertex_fill_color=color,vertex_shape=shape,edge_pen_width = number, output='scheme1.pdf')
```

The error message I get is:

```
python: symbol lookup error: /home/pmj27/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/draw/libgraph_tool_draw.so: undefined symbol: _ZN5Cairo7ContextC1EP6_cairob
```

The first piece of advice I was given on the graph-tool mailing list was that I would need to add the path to the cairo library. To do this I added

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/pmj27/anaconda2/lib"
```

to `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile`. This did not solve my problem and now Nautilus won't start anymore and instead raises the following error:

```
nautilus: symbol lookup error: /home/pmj27/anaconda2/lib/libgdk-3.so.0: undefined symbol: cairo_surface_set_device_scale
```

Does anybody know what I would need to do to solve this problem? How would I find where the cairo libraries are/what file am I looking for there?

Comment: How about replacing that line with export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/pmj27/anaconda2/lib"?

Comment: I have done so. `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` returns `:/home/pmj27/anaconda2/lib‌`. Nautilus starts up happily but python still complains `python: symbol lookup error: /home/pmj27/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/draw/libgraph_tool_draw.so: undefined symbol: _ZN5Cairo7ContextC1EP6_cairob`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using anaconda on Ubuntu then you should do the following:

```
$ conda update conda
$ conda update anaconda
```

This should work. It worked for me.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Got similar issue executing python scripts (using RDKit). Did following:
`$ conda update conda`
`$ conda update anaconda`
This worked for me.